# What happened to Live GPS Tracking in 1.8.0-Lisboa?

Tags: qgis, gps

Dang, I was just getting used to Live GPS Tracking in 1.7.4-Wroclaw.

I downloaded the new version 1.8.0-Lisboa on another computer.  The Live GPS Tracking
thing was in the View pull-down menu in 1.7.4.  But, in 1.8.0-Lisboa, it's not there!!!

Was Live GPS Tracking taken out of 1.8.0-Lisboa?  or maybe Live GPS Tracking is hidden somewhere?

Answer (score 7):

It's still in the *View* menu, but in the *Panels* submenu as *GPS Information*.